# Check if string starts with a dollar sign

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to check if a string starts with a dollar sign but all my attempts simply failed. I've tried StartsWith and -like, I've tried placing the dollar sign to check for within double quotes (escaping it) and within single quotes but nothing seems to work.

```ps
$str = "$abcdef"
$str.StartsWith('$')
$str.StartsWith("`$')
$str -like "`$*'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to use single quotes with your string value, otherwise PowerShell will treat it like a variable when using double quotes. `$str = '$abcdef'`

Comment: `$str = '$abcdef';$str -match '^\$'`

Answer (score 1):

I would use -match in this case.

```
$foo = "`$bar"
$foo -match "^\$"
```

Comment: Why the ^\ before the dollar sign? Wouldn't using '$' be the same?

Comment: it make sure that the `$` sign is at the start of the string